# Add Ubuntu EFI DB and PK back into UEFI

Tags: boot, uefi, secure-boot

I reset my bios and now my Ubuntu 16.04 disk wont book because it can't find the Ubuntu secure boot keys. How can I add these back into my UEFI so it will boot?

When I try to boot I get a message: "Invalid signature detected. Check Secure Boot Policy in Setup"

Answer (score 3):

First, Ubuntu's Shim binary includes a copy of the Canonical (Ubuntu) public key embedded within it, and this binary is signed by Microsoft, so it should be possible to boot without the Canonical key in your firmware. That said, you might run into the issue you describe if you're using another Shim binary -- say, if you're dual-booting with Fedora and are using Fedora's Shim to get the boot process started. (Also, see the very end of this answer....)

In such a case, you should be able to use the MokManager tool to add Canonical's key to the MOK list, which Shim will read. MokManager should be on your disk's [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) alongside the Shim binary. Ideally, MokManager should be an option on whatever GRUB or other boot manager menu you see when you boot. If not, you could adjust the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file to add such an entry, which should look like this:

```
menuentry "MokManager" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod chain
    set root='(hd0,gpt1)'
    chainloader /EFI/fedora/MokManager.efi
}
```

You'll need to adjust that entry for your particular system. In particular, the `set root` option should point to your ESP, which might or might not be `(hd0,gpt1)`; and the path to MokManager might be something other than what I've specified. (I'm showing a Fedora path as an example. Note that you must point to the MokManager binary that comes with the Shim binary you're using.)

There are a couple of other options available to you:

1. You could disable Secure Boot entirely. This is the easiest approach, but Secure Boot exists to improve security, so I don't recommend this as a general rule, especially if you're dual-booting with Windows. Details of how to disable it vary greatly from one system to another. I present several examples on [this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable)
2. You could take full control of Secure Boot and add the Canonical public key to your firmware, as described on [this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/controlling-sb.html) This approach is for those with significant "geek street creds," though; it's technically challenging, and even people who are comfortable with command-line tools are likely to struggle a bit. I mention this approach mainly because your question's title refers to the PK and db, which are keys stored in this way. Canonical's standard approach to Secure Boot does *not* involve modifying these keys, but these variables *are* adjusted when you take full control of Secure Boot. If you did this before, perhaps all you need is a pointer to relevant documentation, so this is it....

Comment: I added a boot entry for MokManager but it will not load because "Invalid signature detected. Check Secure Boot Policy in Setup.

Comment: You don't add an entry for MokManager to the EFI boot list (as maintained by efibootmgr in Ubuntu, for example); you add it to your GRUB configuration. Alternatively, you could copy Shim to some directory other than where GRUB resides and create a new entry for that copy of Shim.

Comment: It won't even boot to grub, it stops because there's an error with secure boot

Comment: Then something is seriously wrong with your Secure Boot configuration. It's unclear to me what the history of your machine is (say, whether you've modified the db and PK Secure Boot keys, as mentioned in your title), what (if any) version of Shim you're using, what your EFI boot entries are, etc. In short, I don't have the information needed to provide more help. I recommend you read all of both of my pages I linked in my main answer and, if that doesn't help, provide *MUCH* more information on your configuration.

Comment: Well everything is still default. The only boot entry for the external drive is called "UEFI", but it won't boot.